# Is it always possible to extend continuous functions defined on a *closed* subset of a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

In the following lemma the authors used Tietze's extension to get $f_1$ and $g_1$.

[image]

I know [this version of Tietze](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188694/tietze-extension-theorem-in-lch-spaces), but it requires the subset to be *compact* not merely *closed*, i.e., continuous functions defined on compact subsets of a LCH space can be extended upto the whole space. But in the above Lemma 1.3 the subset $X_0$ was only assumed to be *closed*; then how did the authors use the Tietze theorem?

**Question**. Suppose $X_0$ is a *closed* subset of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, and $f\in C_0(X_0)$. Is it always possible to extend $f$ to whole of $X$?

**EDIT** The lemma above is in [this pdf](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123600X03904/1-s2.0-0022123684900284/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJ3%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCID73S%2Bk47q%2Fg9nDVFYl6s%2BgUCD22xi7XgY%2BEfi7VvZDUAiEAsE%2BJeYeRQov57UUSUtNCHD6PpKZ8aBJveOqE7l13qWAqgwQI5f%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDP883jhxuHISEA0x%2BirXAxFxvLkZrxrrrcDSCSEWPsplO0bWcioQf40uDBIEe3OfHqHCaoxXfUTkumE%2By%2BsTfmUgzSZe4dNkQHHZGPJ5Ms09YNKYlE0nRzArSlTKRUsm%2B8hKIhetLDJJoqVrs1BjlA9pQxDwpMdIflveJa9dWySe7sDHgxWV0Gjez5T4QXh36%2BrsBB2MCcdPnP%2BMvi%2BYgdHVD4E2x1fBe5SPqc0kOYSq5maeaum6Yr4sK0ujJbko2CRoQLhcexC5N1Cm8W0FYOZDhc995VkO7059g39h8qePvWEa7k0oNVBulFGHvhQssjLbB7f1Hexw9JYe8sN%2BCl8%2F5CQ7fNnHpdDvBHfPdd1WXZ3kr%2BnoNkMTiVXG6hME8EnEOMCFvjUeDDKzvAdEzsNJg8vS3NZRPZJ5i35%2F7bIF0RoO68LZM70IaMqD1AZuLWd%2BkqixJJRCwLdxw1JNiMuJJSo%2B5kE%2FHfMfzf19B2o8VJzzvcWPciHFp1QZyg6mNAKerRxeliBUHes5IVIrce9kruPFpIYssYTzDWQ59NcYtnSyxk36ykUWSgVExkMJ9Tylyi2%2BsFR2PTODTET%2FcB0L46t4%2FFrBB3NwvB9b%2B8PXtmAlTgo%2BvndNFL8yGeVaFoDnCNiOOTDOvbyQBjqlAVYIHNgbpMNLKZa9%2FjuPJnB5lr%2FhumlMw%2FSabCgA8Mw0TFSc4HdwCJ4wVMJh8ddKZk4RKzKeYk74urx4S9%2Bi%2B3W4EeCQmWT5fzV3lkBOERsNjxPUIBVRZJV4nZTRIBIaB%2BTVWwBwiLiIpYkZ33n3ikSODydXo61GZ%2B%2Fw8n9COliwPNWW4ZL7WdvE%2BI1h%2FpdqeaP2P5rmldM0VzfypJ3XE3EC4HHgwg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220218T054710Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYUUADSRUP%2F20220218%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a6f474017f3d79c288c098f80bb394950622a59fd47fbd8a2afd340a3b3122f0&hash=f036d54b6d12ce6136affc40b5ddebe70e2d1930c6d9502f7ebdf8af2a6816e9&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022123684900284&tid=spdf-d1220a16-e6c9-4520-ae82-e3574e0232da&sid=25c6dbca838df642ef0a0199c8edc072d32dgxrqb&type=client&ua=5004005b035259010c03&rr=6df4f58abf349374) (Lemma 1.3).

Comment: You cannot in general extend all functions on closed sets: the existence of non-normal LCH spaces shows this.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. But then how did the authors use Tietze in the proof??

Comment: they must use some weaker version (a positive extension). Look in the index to find the exact theorem they’re quoting.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the Lemma is in the paper "Sub-Stonean Spaces and Corona Sets" by K Grove and Gert Pedersen (Lemma 1.3)..

Comment: I don’t have nor know that paper. Cannot you quote the lemma in the post to be self-contained?

Comment: They must quote a reference at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key extra assumption here is that you are extending not just a continuous function but a continuous function that vanishes at infinity.  If $f\in C_0(X_0)$, then $f$ can be thought of as a function on the one-point compactification $X_0\cup\{\infty\}$ with $f(\infty)=0$.  Now $X_0\cup\{\infty\}$ embeds in the one-point compactification $X\cup\{\infty\}$ (as just the subspace $X_0$ plus the point at infinity) as a closed subspace, so you can extend $f$ to all of $X\cup\{\infty\}$ using the usual Tietze extension theorem.

(Without this extra assumption the result is not true.  For instance, if $X$ is any locally compact Hausdorff space that is not normal and $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint closed subsets that cannot be separated by open sets, then you could take $X_0=A\cup B$ and $f$ that sends $A$ to $0$ and $B$ to $1$.)

Comment: I missed the $C_0(X)$ part... good spot